# Simple code to fill application login form

Tags: java, automation

I am trying to make a small program that fills the username and password field for the application below and press the green button:

[image: login]

What would be the best approach ? I was thinking to the Java Robot class - though I don't know if it
can do this.

Are there easier/better ways ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot class is good way, it perfectly fits this purpose, but you have to determine somehow coordinates of fields, you want to fill. I would probably check every screen pixel (also Robot class) looking for a specific color (green pixel from accept button or yellow pixel from cancel button, or better their combination) and then calculate positions of input fields

Comment: Or maybe I can make the Robot to press the TAB key to move to the next field ?

Comment: yes, you can, but you have to be sure, to have your window focused (i don't now the situation, from which you want to run your filling program)